# Extern for class method

Tags: c++, oop

I want to use extern keyword for class method in C++. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.
I want to force method inline, using __forceinline(without extern I will get unresolved external symbol).   I don't want to put method implementation in this header file, I want put implementation in other .cpp file.
I noticed that method may be inlined automaticly without extern and __forceinline and when method's implementation in .cpp file. How can I force it?
Example code:

```
class Window {
public:
  void Show();
};
```

That's ok!

```
class Window {
public:
  __forceinline void Show();
};
```

Gets unresolved external symbol when I calls this function from other CPP.
With extern I gets:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjlkX.png)

For simple functions extern __forceinline works fine:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnQL8.png)

Comment: Why do you want to force inline? Compiler is probably much better than you at optimizing code.

Comment: Code obfuscation. I want the function body to be repeated every time where it is called.

Comment: This won't go anywhere, use pimpl or abstract interfaces to hide implementation.

Answer (score 2):

#### You cannot specify `extern` for a member function.

The standard clarifies this in `[dcl.stc]/5`:

> The extern specifier can be applied only to the names of variables and functions. The extern specifier cannot be used in the declaration of class members or function parameters.

When you use extern, you say to the compiler that you declare a variable or a function, but without defining it.  In the case of member functions, this is not needed: they can always be declared in a class body without being defined:

```
class A { 
public: 
       void f();  // you can define it in which ever compilation unit (cpp) you want
};  
...
// Else where...may be in another cpp
void A::f() {...}
```

The linker will resolve the symbols when needed.

### The inline is not so useful

The standard  in `[dcl.inline]/2` says that inline is not guaranteed:

> The inline specifier indicates to the implementation that inline
>   substitution of the function body at the point of call is to be
>   preferred to the usual function call mechanism. **An implementation is
>   not required to perform this inline substitution** at the point of call;

Furthermore, `[dcl.inline]/6` explains that `inline` and defined eleswhere is not something meant to work well:

> An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case.

(odr says that all the definitions must be exactly the same definition each time) 
(in every translation unit means in every cpp or the headers therein included)

On the other side, the global optimizer of some modern compilers is able to achieve similar performance effects than inlined functions, and this  accross compilation units (cpp).

### Implementation specific forceinline

[MSVC 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) uses `inline` carefully,  making a cost/benefit analysis to decide whether or not to inline.

`forceinline` allows you to overrule the compiler's judgement.  But it comes with all the requirements of the normal `inline`: so you need to have a definition of the function in the same compilation unit to get it work.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. You cannot declare a member function as `extern`.  These already have external linkage.
2. For the compiler to inline a function or method, it has to be defined (as opposed to declared) in the header file.  This is so that the compiler can see it when compiling code that calls the function.

So, just put the function body in the header file and drop the `extern`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to put method implementation in this header file, I want put implementation in other .cpp file.

Sounds to me like you just want to have all declarations in one file like this:

This is your `window.h`- file:

```
class Window 
{
public:
  void Show();
};
```

To have the implementation in another file, you have to use the scope operator.
This is the other `window.cpp`- file, in which you have the actual implementation of the function:

```
#include "window.h"

Window::Show()
{
    // Your implementation goes here
}
```

I hope I understood your question right and this helps.